Function wrapper generic type determination
function callbackWrapper<T = string>(cb?: () => T): T  {
    return cb?.() ?? 'default value';
  }
 
const a = callbackWrapper(() => 7); // a should be number
const b = callbackWrapper(() => true); // b should be boolean
const c = callbackWrapper(() => 'string'); // c should be string
const d = callbackWrapper(); // d should be string ('default value')


How to change function callbackWrapper header typings, so return type would not throw error
Tried castring return type, which worked, but then again you can cast anything with "7 as unknown as string[]" and it will work. So that is not a sollution

TS doesn't have a way to allow default function arguments and default type arguments to work with each other, see ms/TS#58977 and the linked q/a above. Right now someone can call callbackWrapper<number>() and TS will pretend it can return a number. All workarounds involve some loss of type safety for the caller or the implementer. I'd do it this way, which makes things safe for callers, at least.

Since callbackWrapper can return any type given by the parameter type T, it's possible that the return type is incompatible with 'default value'.
Instead, you should explicitly state you expect to return T and 'default value' (or string):
function callbackWrapper<T = string>(cb?: () => T): T|'default value'  {
  return cb?.() ?? 'default value';
}

